# Change Field Type from Int to Float

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm helping a co-worker with a Drupal (6) issue, but I've never used Drupal before. The client wants to store  decimal values in a field that was originally defined as an integer. I can't believe that this isn't possible without losing content or without doing a bunch of SQL copying, but I can't find anything that says, "sure, you can update the field type pretty easily, just do...".

Is this possible? So far:

- We've altered the the `content_type_thing` table so that the `_value` field is now a `float` data type rather than an `int`.
- We've updated the `content_node_field` table so the `type` value for that field is `number_float`

Now we can change the value from 1840 to 1840.25 without getting a validation error, but the `.25` never gets saved. It gets chopped off and we get `18.00` in the database.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Before anyone asks, I have read [this post](http://drupal.org/node/769784), but it looks like the recommendation involves a bunch of data migration. I just can't believe that there's not a way to change the data type in place.

Comment: Is there a way to define a `decimal` type rather than float, so that the decimal places could be set? Also may be important if this is for monetary values.

Comment: It's not monetary and, afaik, Drupal doesn't support number fields that way.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straight forward my friend. download this module
http://drupal.org/project/formatted_number

When you install it, go to the content type and change that field to use float.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a solution but it's not easy and if you don't know exactly what
you're doing it may have side effects
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/79378/changing-a-field-type-from-integer-to-decimal